# What is the difference between "addOptional" and "addParameter" functions in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function

What is the difference between `addOptional` and `addParameter` in MATLAB for creating functions?

MATLAB documention of these two functions:

> **addOptional**(p,argName,default) adds optional input, argName, to the
>   input parser scheme of inputParser object, p. When the inputs that you
>   are checking do not include a value for this optional input, the input
>   parser assigns the default value to the input.
>
> addOptional(p,argName,default,validationFcn) specifies a validation
>   function for the input argument.
>
> **addParameter**(p,paramName,default) adds parameter name and value
>   argument paramName to the input parser scheme of inputParser object,
>   p. When the inputs that you are checking do not include a value for
>   this optional parameter, the input parser assigns the default value.
>
> addParameter(p,paramName,default,validationFcn) specifies a validation
>   function for the input argument.

Comment: Parameters consist of a name-value-pair, i.e. you pass first a string defining the name of the parameter and then its value. Parameters come after the other arguments, but otherwise their order does not matter. `addOptional` refers to an input argument, i.e. a variable that you pass to a function. Both "functions" are in fact methods of the input parser class. Typically, you use that class within a function and pass it the function inputs you want to parse. You parse the inputs

Answer (score 4):

addParameter adds a Parameter/Value pair to the input syntax of your function. For example, if you had a function called myFunction in which you were using the input parser:

```
addRequired(p,'x')
addParameter(p,'Foo',1)
```

Would add:

```
myFunction(x,'Foo',value)
```

As a valid syntax with a default value of 1. In parameter value pairs, the name of the parameter is specified with a string or character array, followed by a value specification.

```
addOptional(p,'Foo',value)
```

Would add:

```
myFunction(x,value)
```

As an optional positional argument. In this case, you only specify the value of the optional argument without specifying a parameter name.